# How to populate a CTE with a list of values in Sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite

I am working with SQLite and straight C. I have a C array of ids of length `N` that I am compiling into a string with the following format:

```
'id1', 'id2', 'id3', ... 'id[N]'
```

I need to build queries to do several operations that contain comparisons to this list of ids, an example of which might be...

```
SELECT id FROM tableX WHERE id NOT IN (%s);
```

... where `%s` is replaced by the string representation of my array of ids. For complicated queries and high values of `N`, this obviously produces some very ungainly queries, and I would like to clean them up using common-table-expressions. I have tried the following:

```
WITH id_list(id) AS
(VALUES(%s))
SELECT * FROM id_list;
```

This doesn't work because SQLite expects a column for for each value in my string. My other failed attempt was

```
WITH id_list(id) AS
(SELECT (%s))
SELECT * FROM id_list;
```

but this throws a syntax error at the comma. Does SQLite syntax exist to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite supports VALUES clauses with multiple rows, so you can write:

```sql
WITH id_list(id) AS (VALUES ('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3'), ...
```

However, this is not any more efficient than just listing the IDs in IN.

You could write all the IDs into a temporary table, but this would not make sense unless you have measured the performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have found is to reformat my string as follows:

```
VALUES('id1') UNION VALUES('id2') ... UNION VALUES('id[N]')
```

Then, the following query achieves the desired result:

```
WITH id_list(id) AS
(%s)
SELECT * FROM id_list;
```

However, I am not totally satisfied with this solution. It seems inefficient.